# Zend redirect in a view script

Tags: php, zend-framework, redirect

1. Is it possible to redirect a view script via using a zend method ?
2. Or would it just be simpler to use a php redirect: `<?php header('Location: $myurl') ?>`

Comment: Define "redirect a view script"

Comment: @phil view script - file exists in the `application/layouts/scripts` folder. Where sometimes controller variables aren't in scope without directly adding it to the $this->view method

Comment: To re-iterate my comment, what do you mean by "redirect a view script". That statement to me does not make any sense. You can return a redirect response by sending a `Location` header but I can't see how the verb "redirect" applies to the noun "view script"

Comment: @phil i think we can save our discussion for english.SE . No time for semantics; everyone else understood my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your controller (use location header):

```
$this->_redirect($url);
```

or

```
$redirector = $this->getHelper('Redirector');
/* @var $redirector Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector */
$redirector->gotoUrl($url);
```

you can also use:

```
$redirector->gotoRoute(
    array(
        'action'     => 'my-action',
        'controller' => 'my-controller'
    )
);
```

If you want to use a different view script than the default:

```
$this->renderScript('/my-controller/my-view.phtml');
```